# Insert Username in to file path Powershell

Tags: powershell

We are in the process of trying to tidy up our users home directories and speed up some office 2007 performance by moving all their templates in to a new directory on their user drive (U:).  During my initial tests I can get the below script to work fine though it has the obvious problem of only working for my username.  Is there a way to get it to take the currently logging in user?  Before this would be handled by %username% and from a brief scan of the internet apparently:

```
$[Environment]::UserName
```

Should work.  However I seem to be getting errors. Is there a better way to achieve the current logging in users name in to the file path?

```
if (!(Test-Path -path '\\SERVER\PATH\TO FILES\$[Environment]::UserName\Normal\'))
{
New-Item '\\SERVER\PATH\TO FILES\$[Environment]::UserName\Normal\' -type directory
##Move-Item \\SERVER\PATH\TO FILES\$env:username\Normal.dot \\\SERVER\PATH\TO FILES\$env:username\Normal\
## Move-Item \\SERVER\PATH\TO FILES\$env:username\*.dotm \\SERVER\PATH\TO FILES\%username%\Normal\
}
else
{
"No work to do"
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085744/how-to-get-current-username-in-windows-powershell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems.  If you want variable/expression substitution to take place in a string, you need to use quotation-marks, not apostrophes, to enclose the string.  In this case, you also need to add some parenthesis to denote an expression within the string.

```
"\\SERVER\PATH\TO FILES\$([Environment]::UserName)\Normal\"
```

Comment: `$env:USERNAME` is more PowerShell-ish, perhaps: `"\\SERVER\PATH\TO FILES\$env:USERNAME\Normal\"`