# Get current user on local machine using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to retrieve the displayname / full name of the user currently logged in on the computer. Is there anyway to do this without using AD?

Comment: Please take a look at this [thread ("How to get current username in Windows Powershell?")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085744/how-to-get-current-username-in-windows-powershell).

Comment: @CanBilgin This only gives me the name of the computer instead of the name displayed when I open Start Menu.

Comment: Like the Full Names I get from the command: Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount. Although I want the current users full name :)

Comment: @Colour: Don't just look at the first answer. E.g. `[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name` will return what you want.

Comment: @Joey This command still only gives me the name of the computer :).

Answer (score 0):

`whoami` provides that. It's not a PowerShell cmdlet, but should still suffice.

Comment: This gives the computername :). Not the displayname.