# Applying ACL Permissions using PowerShell Set-Acl

Tags: powershell, acl

```
New-Item -Type Directory -Path "C:\MyFolder"
$Acl = Get-Acl "C:\MyFolder"
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("username", "FullControl", "Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl -Path "C:\MyFolder" -AclObject $Acl
```

Hi, when I got the above code and applied it using my own settings - the user account entries are added for the folder but, no Permissions are applied (none ticked)

Can anyone help with why this might be?

Thanks

Comment: Your snippet works for me. Do you have any error message? An UnauthorizedAccessException?

Comment: No errors - the accounts get added to the sec perms in the folder - you can see them there but no perms ticked. Only diff between what im actually running is I reference a variable with the user account stored in - but that works as - otherwise, the account wouldn't show up in there.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. Hope I got the point. Please consider reviewing your question and add some additional information and screenshots to it so others understand what you mean. (I'd personally see this question better placed on superuser)

Comment: If my answer solved your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comment describes the following behaviour:

Your PowerShell script succeeds but if you check the permissions with the explorers properties dialog, you will see the following:

[image: permissions with unfilled checkboxes]

This is pretty confusing as a PowerShell query will confirm:

```
PS> Get-Acl .|fl


Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::D:\temp\myfolder
Owner  : clijsters\clijsters
Group  : clijsters\Kein
Access : clijsters\NEWUSER Allow  FullControl
        VORDEFINIERT\Administratoren Allow  FullControl
        VORDEFINIERT\Administratoren Allow  268435456
        NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
        [...]
```

Your ACL changed. If you scroll down the list of your checkboxes you will notice, that "Special permissions" is checked and if you click on "Advanced" you will notice, your permissions are set.

EDIT:
As mentioned by @AnsgarWiechers, I missed a part describing *why* the permissions added with `New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("username", "FullControl", "Allow")` are listed as *Special permissions*.

Like described on MSDN, [`FileSystemAccessRule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule(v=vs.110).aspx) has 4 constructors, where some accept `InheritanceFlags` and `PropagationFlags` (e.g. [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfe70whw(v=vs.110).aspx) fits your needs). If you use them and define inheritance behaviour, the permissions will show up as normal ones.

Comment: Thanks! What a Totally cool way of adding folder permissions as part of a wider scripted solution.

Comment: The reason why the permissions are displayed as "special permissions" is because you don't define inheritance, so the permissions are applied to "this folder only". Add container and object inheritance to the ACE and the permissions will show up as "regular" full control.

Comment: I don't get why this answer is _unaccepted_. Jus tsaw it coincidentally on my profile. @Royston: Would you explain, that I can improve my answer?

Comment: @Clijsters classed as an answer now. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Today I was trying to compile ILSpy and encountered `AL1078: Error signing assembly` which is a permissions issue.  An amalgamation of answers is shown.

This powershell script assigns `$CurUsr` to the token for the currently logged in user and `$CurTgt` as the folder whose permissions are being altered.  Change them as required.

Add permission:

```
$CurTgt = "C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys"
$CurUsr = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$acl = Get-Acl $CurTgt
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($CurUsr,"FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl $CurTgt
```

Remove permission:

```
$CurTgt = "C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys"
$CurUsr = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$acl = Get-Acl $CurTgt
$usersid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.Ntaccount ($CurUsr)
$acl.PurgeAccessRules($usersid)
$acl | Set-Acl $CurTgt
```

References:

[Manage ACLs](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/04/18/how-to-manage-file-system-acls-with-powershell-scripts)
[Inheritance](https://chrisfederico.wordpress.com/2008/02/01/setting-acl-on-a-file-or-directory-in-powershell/#comment-109)
[Current User](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2085759/9789571)