# How to get an Azure Active Directory username in Windows Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to get the current Windows username & domain from Powershell on a Windows 10 Azure Active Directory (AAD) joined machine.

I've tried the tips at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085744/how-to-get-current-username-in-windows-powershell), but none of them seem to work for Azure Active Directory-joined machines.

e.g. for the user: `Jonathan Doe, john@example.com` you'll get only the users' proper name & `AzureAD` (not their username or 'real' domain):

```
$env:UserName --> JonathanDoe
$env:UserDomain --> AzureAD
[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name --> AzureAD\JonathanDoe
```

Does anyone know how to get any part of the user's actual credential or specific Azure AAD domain? (e.g. `john` or `example.com` or ideally `john@example.com`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run the following command in PowerShell, the output will display the user name in UPN format.You can get both of the username and domain name from that.

```
whoami.exe /UPN
```

In addition, the program 'whoami.exe' provides many other parameters for getting additional information about current user. You can type the following command for more details about 'whoami.exe'.

```
whoami.exe /?
```

Comment: Most useful but running cmd line tools and capturing the output is a common process, it always smacks of a fudge. Anyone know of a .NET or WinAPI call that achieves the same as whoami.exe /UPN?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how official this is, but I found a link in the registry that contains the username which is user@company.com.  This was under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IdentityStore\Cache\xxx\IdentityCache\xxx.`  The key name was UserName.  You can use the [built-in powershell registry provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/working-with-registry-entries) to navigate to this registry entry.

Comment: There appears to be multiple keys with very similar information in that area of the registry. However, I guess you could match $Env:Username against SAMName in the first one you found. Bit smelly code :-)