# How to get login username from within a PowerShell CmdLet

Tags: c#, powershell, credentials

I have authored a PowerShell CmdLet in C#. It is being invoked from a C# application running as a Windows service under the username SYSTEM. The calling (service) application performs a New-PSSession (adding a Credential parameter having username "Joe") followed by an Import-PSSession to create the runspace for the CmdLet.

When the CmdLet executes, I can use Environment.UserName to get the current username, but it is SYSTEM (from the service process). What I want is to recover the username supplied in the PowerShell session credential (in this case, "Joe"). How can I recover that credential within the context of the executing C# CmdLet?

I have already seen the suggestions contained in [How do I get the current username in Windows PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085744/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-windows-powershell); they do not work; they only give me the SYSTEM username under which the invoking process is running, not the "Joe" credential it supplied to create the PowerShell session.

FWIW, the PowerShell session is given a connectionuri which in the general case would usually be a remote system, but in the specific example is 127.0.0.1 (localhost).

Comment: Try $env:username from the duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085744/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-windows-powershell

Comment: @ClaudiuA The CmdLet is C#; the suggested answers are ps script. I assume $env:UserName is equivalent to System.Environment.UserName, which gives me "SYSTEM" (not what I am looking for). I assume [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name is System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, which also gives me "SYSTEM", not "Joe"

Comment: When I enter a remote PSSession, `$env:UserName` shows the username I've connected as: `$cred = Get-Credential; $sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName server.domain.tld -Credential $cred; Enter-PSSession -Session $sess; $env:UserName`

Comment: I found the problem. The Import-PSSession was failing because of unresolvable conflicts. As a result, the session in which the CmdLet was being executed remained that of the calling process. When I resolved the conflicts (being very selective about what is actually imported), the CmdLet executed with the correct credentials and System.Environment.UserName contained the expected value.

Comment: @CRobinson, please post your findings as an answer - it'll help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this case turned out to be related to the way the PowerShell session was created and imported. The import actually "failed silently", so the CmdLet was executed in the process "native" context.

The `New-PSSession` command specified a configuration (`-ConfigurationName MyConfiguration`). This configuration was properly registered, but essentially did nothing. As a result, the `Import-PSSession` attempted to import a default session with the desired module included. This introduced a number of conflicts, causing the import to fail. Since the CmdLet is already installed on the computer (we are looping back because the `New-PSSession` specifies `-ConnectionUri http://127.0.0.1:5985/WSMAN`) it appeared to work, so the failed import was unnoticed. The only clue to the issue was the discrepancy in username.

The problem was resolved by properly defining the configuration, using `RestrictedRemoteServer`:

```
$sessionConfigurationName = 'MyConfiguration'
$tempFile = $env:TEMP + "\psconfig.pssc"
New-PSSessionConfigurationFile -SessionType RestrictedRemoteServer -ModulesToImport MyModule -Path $tempFile
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name $sessionConfigurationName -NoServiceRestart -Path $tempFile
Remove-Item -Path $tempFile
```

This allowed the `New-PSSession` to create a session which could be imported successfully without conflicts. The resulting session acquired and operated under the correct credential.