# Powershell environment variable %username%

Tags: powershell

I would like to insert environment variable `%username%` in this powershell script:

```
$o = new-object -com shell.application
$o.Namespace('\\xx.local\Employee Personal Folders\Employee\%username%\Scan Folder').Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome")
```

How can I go about that?

Cheers in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the current username in Windows PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085744/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-windows-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell uses a different format for environment variables.  For example, `%USERNAME%` is specified as `$env:USERNAME`.  Try updating your code as follows:

```
$o = new-object -com shell.application
$o.Namespace("\\xx.local\Employee Personal Folders\Employee\$env:USERNAME\Scan Folder").Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome")
```

Note the double-quotes around the path string - this is required for PowerShell to automatically replace the variable.

Comment: Cool! I actually did some research prior to asking my question and I did try the $env:Username. However, I was using ' ' rather than " ". Causing the script to fail.